# CORS on Symfony 2 errors BeSimpleSOAPBundle calling WebService with Javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services, symfony, cors

I'm working with [BeSimpleSOAPBundle](http://besim.pl/SoapBundle/) to do my web service on symfony2 . I  test my web service with [SOA Client  extension firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/soa-client/)  and I can see that my web service it's ok , but when Try to test with javascript this fails. I get the following mistakes from console browser

```js
OPTIONS http://192.168.0.68/controlid/web/app_dev.php/ws/loginOperador?wdls 405  (Method Not Allowed) jquery.js:4
OPTIONS http://192.168.0.68/controlid/web/app_dev.php/ws/loginOperador?wdls No   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin   'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. jquery.js:4
XMLHttpRequest cannot load    http://192.168.0.68/controlid/web/app_dev.php/ws/loginOperador?wdls. No 'Access-Control-   Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is    therefore not allowed access. (index):1
```

The next code is the way to call  my web service with javascript

```js
function CallService()
{
    var webServiceURL = 'http://192.168.0.68/controlid/web/app_dev.php/ws/loginOperador?wdls';
    var soapMessage = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><goodbye xmlns="http://controlid/ws/loginOperador/1.0/"><name>'+$('#nombre').val()+'</name></goodbye></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';
   jQuery.support.cors = true;
   //Llamamos a la función AJAX de JQuery
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: webServiceURL,
      crossDomain : true,
      cache: false,
      data: soapMessage,
      processData: false,
      dataType: "xml",
      contentType: "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
      success: OnSuccess,
      error: OnError
   });
   return false;
}
```

This is the code of my web services on symfony:

```
/**
  * Método que se encarga de verificar si un operador
  * puede tener acceso desde la aplicación móvil.
  *
  * @Soap\Method("login")
  * @Soap\Param("pin", phpType = "string")
  * @Soap\Result(phpType = "string")
*/
public function loginAction( $pin )
{
    $em =  $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();       
    try 
    {
        $operador = $em->getRepository('controlidRondasBundle:Operador')->findOneBy(array('pin'=>$pin));
        if( empty($operador) )
        {
            return sprintf('Acceso denegado');
        }
        else{
            return sprintf('Bienvenido %s!', $operador->getNombre() );
        }
    } 
    catch (\Doctrine\Orm\NoResultException $e) 
    {
        return sprintf('Acceso denegado');
    }
}
```

An this is the setup of my service on symfony ( app/conf/config.yml)

```php
be_simple_soap: 
   services:
        DemoApi:
            namespace:     http://controlid/ws/DemoApi/1.0/
            binding:       rpc-literal
            resource:      "@controlidRondasBundle/Controller/RegisterController.php"
            resource_type: annotation
        loginOperador:
            namespace:     http://controlid/ws/loginOperador/1.0/
            binding:       rpc-literal
            resource:      "@controlidSeguridadBundle/Controller/OperatorSecurityController.php"
            resource_type: annotation
```

And routing_dev.yml:

```php
_besimple_soap:
    resource: "@BeSimpleSoapBundle/Resources/config/routing/webservicecontroller.xml"
    prefix:   /ws
```

Someone could say me what do I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: I can't see anywhere in your code that is setting the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header, which the message makes clear is required. Also, why on earth would you want to mix SOAP and JS? (Sorry, but I find SOAP a needlessly complex way of failing to achieve interoperability between environments.)

Comment: 1. how to setup the header with Access-Control-Allow-origin? 2. `SOAP + JS` because The web service is consumed by a **phonegap** application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The   thing that  I had to do is setup my [apache server](http://www.barneyparker.com/configure-apache-to-accept-cross-site-xmlhttprequests-on-debian/)

1. Activate the module

```php
a2enmod headers
service apache2 restart
```

2 . And edit the file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`

```js
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ....

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

...

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

...
    #The things that I added 

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, content-type"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"

    #End of the thigns that I added 

</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT**

The above answer only works on localhost, but when I tryed to do it on hosting or whaterver cloud, The mistake persevere, so the answer was [the magic bundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle)

The installation :

```
php composer.phar require nelmio/cors-bundle:~1.0
```

Then add to `project/app/AppKernel.php`

```php
public function registerBundles()
{
   $bundles = array(
    ...
    new Nelmio\CorsBundle\NelmioCorsBundle(),
    ...
   );
   ...
}
```

Now the setup of the bundle and my paths on `project/app/config/config.yml` add

```php
nelmio_cors:
   defaults:
       allow_credentials: true
       allow_origin: []
       allow_headers: []
       allow_methods: []
       expose_headers: []
       max_age: 0
       hosts: []
   paths:
    '^/':
        allow_origin: ['*']
        allow_headers: ['origin', 'content-type']
        allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE','OPTIONS']
        max_age: 3600
```

To summary **it's works!!**