# Using FOSJsRoutingBundle with simple html pages & angularJs

Tags: angularjs, symfony

As I've asked in my last question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843829/consuming-restful-symfony2-with-angularjs-client) I try to write an angularJs client to consume symfony2 restful api.
This is my angular module :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.factory("services", ['$http', function($http) {
var serviceBase = '/myproject/web/app_dev.php/api/';


var obj = {};
obj.getCategories = function(){
return $http.get(serviceBase + 'categories');
}
obj.getCategorie = function(CostumerID){
return $http.get(serviceBase + 'costumer?id=' + CostumerID);
}

obj.deleteCostumer = function (id) {
return $http.delete(serviceBase + 'deleteCostumer?id=' + id).then(function (status) {
return status.data;
});
};

return obj;
}]);

app.controller('listCtrl', function ($scope, services) {
services.getCategories().then(function(data){
$scope.categorie = data.data;
});
});
```

I have created an index page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp" ng-app lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
    <body>
        <div>
        <div class="container">
        <div data-ng-view="" id="ng-view"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <script src="/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/app/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I found that I can use FOSJsRoutingBundle to generate route for my app but in the documentation I should add this two line to my code :

```
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {'callback': 'fos.Router.setData'}) }}"></script>
```

But I don't use twig and I don't know hwo can I use it?

Also I don't know which url should I ask at first time to run the application because when I ask for index I have a blank page :(

Can someone help me and tell me what should I do or what I've missed?

Comment: You have missed something after "**should add this two line to my code :**"

Comment: btw, develop UI as separate project.

Comment: Thanks @SergioIvanuzzo for your comments.Ijust add the two lines I've missed. Yes I try to develop backend part and frontend part as separate part but I don't know how can I make connection between the two parts. even if I call api url in my app.js I still have a blank page when I call the index.html

Comment: your actions in controller shoud returns JsonResponse(), so you can easily get it by simple `$http` request from angular.

Comment: That's exactly what I've did .. I test the response of my controller whith postman (google extension) and it a JsonResponse..should I add something else to reformat this response even if it is Json ?

Comment: I think, when you trying to access Symfony2 project from external resourse, you getting error "CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' headers missing". So, you need to configure CORS. For example see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23643644/5397119

Comment: Not really .. I don't have any error in the debugger.The only problem I have is that even if the **app.js** is loaded no treatment is performed. When I verify the networks in the debugger their is no call for any method or function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95838/discussion-between-sergio-ivanuzzo-and-akino).

Answer (score 0):

For default configuration, you can get FOSJSRouting js files from:

1. @FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/public/js/router.js
2. js/fos_js_routes.js

Then you can use the assetic in symfony (read this [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#using-named-assets) for more info), include js files above, and specify the output files for example to js/compiled.js.
Then update your html to something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp" ng-app lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
    <body>
        <div>
        <div class="container">
        <div data-ng-view="" id="ng-view"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <script src="/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/compiled.js"></script>
        <script src="/app/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In your app.js, you can get url from Symfony Routing in this way

```
var url = window.Routing.generate(route, params, absolute);
```

Hope it helps